# mnesia equivalent of ets:lookup_element()?

Tags: erlang

What is the mnesia equivalent for ets:lookup_element(Tab, Key, Pos)? I am struggling to find it using the man pages and mnesia tutorials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use match_object(Tab, Pattern, LockKind) in mnesia http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#match_object-3.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only that position, then you cannot avoid `qlc:q/1`. Query List comprehension are the only read methods that will enable you to manipulate how mnesia gives you the results.

```
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl").

select(Q)->
    case mnesia:is_transaction() of
        false -> 
            F = fun(QH)-> qlc:e(QH) end,
            %% mnesia:transaction(F);
            mnesia:activity(transaction,F,[Q],mnesia_frag);
        true -> qlc:e(Q)
    end.

-record(book,{title,isbn,price,category}).

book_title({book,ISBN})->
    select(qlc:q([X#book.title || X <- mnesia:table(book),X#book.isbn == ISBN])).
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347753/431620) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9356588/431620)

Comment: Makes me appreciate the other answer (no offence intended)

Comment: At first you said you wanted only the object at a given position in the record. Does not matter anyways :)